# How to resolve ESLint error unable to resolve path to module 'react-native'

Tags: react-native, eslintrc

New to react native and trying to setup ESLint in my project.  I am getting this specific error:

Unable to resolve path to module 'react-native'. (import/no-unresolved)

I searched on SO and found similar threads, but nothing seems to work.  I tried cleaning the npm cache as well.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
```

There is a red underline on my index.js file in the project root (using Atom editor) and under the word react in the above code snippet.

Comment: the most common solution? ignore it. every linter is going to have issues with pathing

Answer (score 0):

As per the react native guide

> AppRegistry should be required early in the require sequence to make
>   sure the JS execution environment is setup before other modules are
>   required.

If you are struggling with es-lint configuration and guess that it's showing false error then you can add .eslinrc file at the root of the project and configure eslint rule as required. I suggest airbnb standard, this guide show full setup [here](https://thecodersblog.com/react-eslint-vscode/)

Comment: @StuartPaton I have updated the link. Hope this helps.